# why salt archive.extracted command create the same nested root directory

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to extract tar file using salt archive.extracted command

its state skeleton looks like this:

```
download_extract:
archive.extracted:
    - name: /opt/
    - if_missing: /opt/
    - source: {{ settings.binaries_url }}
    - source_hash: {{ settings.hash_url }}
    - user: {{ settings.env.user }}
    - group: {{ settings.env.user }}
    - enforce_ownership_on: /opt/
```

the tar contains a root directory ( /foo and files under it).

what I expect is to get:

```
/opt/foo/*all the content @ foo*
```

but what I get is:

```
/opt/foo/foo/*all the content @ foo*
```

can u help?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tar archive probably has a top-level or leading directory.
You can skip this directory by adding the two items below.

```
download_extract:
  archive.extracted:
    - name: /opt/
    - if_missing: /opt/
    - source: {{ settings.binaries_url }}
    - source_hash: {{ settings.hash_url }}
    - user: {{ settings.env.user }}
    - group: {{ settings.env.user }}
    - enforce_ownership_on: /opt/
    - enforce_toplevel: False
    - options: --strip-components=1
```